# regular expression for the extracting multiple patterns

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have string like this

```
string="""Claim Status\r\n[Primary Status: Paidup to Rebilled]\r\nGeneral Info.\r\n[PA Number: #######]\r\nClaim Insurance: Modified\r\n[Ins. Mode: Primary], [Corrected Claim Checked], [ICN: #######], [Id: ########]"""

tokens=re.findall('(.*)\r\n(.*?:)(.*?])',string)
```

Output

```
 ('Claim Status', '[Primary Status:', ' Paidup to Rebilled]')
 ('General Info.', '[PA Number:', ' R180126187]')
 ('Claim Insurance: Modified', '[Ins. Mode:', ' Primary]')
```

Wanted output:

```
 ('Claim Status', 'Primary Status:Paidup to Rebilled')
 ('General Info.', 'PA Number:R180126187')
 ('Claim Insurance: Modified', 'Ins. Mode:Primary','ICN: ########', 'Id: #########')
```

Comment: The last result can only be obtained with a post-processing step as you cannot define a variable amount of groups in a regex pattern. If it is 3 you will always get 3 captures in the resulting list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may achieve what you need with a solution like this:

```
import re
s="""Claim Status\r\n[Primary Status: Paidup to Rebilled]\r\nGeneral Info.\r\n[PA Number: #######]\r\nClaim Insurance: Modified\r\n[Ins. Mode: Primary], [Corrected Claim Checked], [ICN: #######], [Id: ########]"""
res = []
for m in re.finditer(r'^(.+)(?:\r?\n\s*\[(.+)])?\r?$', s, re.M):
    t = []
    t.append(m.group(1).strip())
    if m.group(2):
        t.extend([x.strip() for x in m.group(2).strip().split('], [') if ':' in x])
    res.append(tuple(t))
print(res)
```

See the [Python online demo](https://ideone.com/OzKQjl). Output:

```
[('Claim Status', 'Primary Status: Paidup to Rebilled'), ('General Info.', 'PA Number: #######'), ('Claim Insurance: Modified', 'Ins. Mode: Primary', 'ICN: #######', 'Id: ########')]
```

With the `^(.+)(?:\r?\n\s*\[(.+)])?\r?$` regex, you match two consecutive lines with the second being optional (due to the `(?:...)?` optional non-capturing group), the first is captured into Group 1 and the subsequent one (that starts with `[` and ends with `]`) is captured into Group 2. (Note that `\r?$` is necessary since in the multiline mode `$` only matches before a newline and not a carriage return.) Group 1 value is added to a temporary list, then the contents of the second group is split with `], [` (if you are not sure about the amount of whitespace, you may use `re.split(r']\s*,\s*\[', m.group(2))`) and then only add those items that contain a `:` in them to the temporary list.

Comment: can you update your code it's not working for the given input i have edited the string plz i will be thankfull i new to python

Answer (score 0):

You are getting three elements per result because you are using "capturing" regular expressions. Rewrite your regexp like this to combine the second and third match:

```
re.findall('(.*)\r\n((?:.*?:)(?:.*?]))',string)
```

A group delimited by `(?:...)` (instead of `(...)`) is "non-capturing", i.e. it doesn't count as a match target for `\1` etc., and it does not get "seen" by `re.findall`. I have made both your groups non-capturing, and added a single capturing (regular) group around them.